# Find the two other sides in a 15-30-135 triangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

A triangle has angle measures of 15, 30, and 135 degrees. The side opposite the 15 angle is x feet, the side opposite the 30 angle is y feet, and the side opposite the 135 angle is 2 feet.

Find x and y without the law of sine.

Comment: Are you allowed to use Law of Sines?

Comment: whatever it takes to find x and y

Comment: Do you know what the law of sines is?

Comment: You got three angles and one side. Law of Sines allows you to find another side. Since all three angles are already known, there is no ambiguous case. You need to look up what the Law of Sines formula is...

Comment: Fit it into the tip of 30-60-90.  The angle opposite ther 135 is 2 feet so the altitude of the triangle is 1 foot.  (As the altitude is one side of a 30-60-90.  The complementary angle of 135 is 45 so y is the hypotenuse of a isoceles right triangle with sides 1 so y = $\sqrt2}$.  And 1 + x = $\sqrt 3$ so 1 + x is base of the 30-60-90.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw a 30-60-90 triangle with hypotenuse =2, height = 1, and base = $\sqrt 3$.

Inside it construct a 90-45-45 triangle so that the 90-45-45- and 90-60-30 share the altitude equal =1.  The base is 1.  And the hypotenuse is $\sqrt 2$.  The line on the opposite side of the this base, extending to the base of the original 30-60-90 triangle will be of length $\sqrt 3 - 1$.

Now remove the 90-45-45 from the 90=60-30 and you are left with a 15-30-135 triangle.  This is *your* triangle.

The side opposite the 135 is the original hypontenuse = 2.  The side opposite the 30 is the hypotenuse of the 90-45-45 and is equal to $\sqrt 2$.  The remaining side is $\sqrt 3 - 1$, the base of the 30-60-90 minus the base of the 90-45-45..

Comment: Clean and very intuitive. +1

Answer (score 1):

Apply sine rule in given triangle as follows 
$$\frac{x}{\sin 15^\circ}=\frac{y}{\sin 30^\circ}=\frac{2}{\sin 135^\circ}$$
considering first & third, 
$$\frac{x}{\sin 15^\circ}=\frac{2}{\sin 135^\circ}$$

$$x=\frac{2\sin 15^\circ}{\sin 135^\circ}=\frac{2\sin (45^\circ-30^\circ)}{\sin 45^\circ}=\frac{2\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\frac1{\sqrt 2}}=\color{red}{\sqrt 3-1}$$
similarly, considering second & third, 
$$\frac{y}{\sin 30^\circ}=\frac{2}{\sin 135^\circ}$$
 $$y=\frac{2\sin 30^\circ}{\sin 135^\circ}=\frac{2\cdot \frac{1}{2}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}}=\color{red}{\sqrt 2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  Draw the triangle in a coordinate plane.  Call the triangle $ABC$ with angle $A$ equal to 135 degrees and at the origin.  Let $B$ be the 30 degree angle and position it along the positive $x$-axis.  Let $C$ be the 15 degree angle.  $C$ will be in the Second Quadrant because of the 135 degree angle.  The side $BC$ is 2 feet.  Drop the perpendicular from vertex $C$ down to the $x$-axis.  This forms a 30-60-90 right triangle $BCD$ with angle $D$ the 90 degree angle.  From there, you can use this triangle to help you figure out the sides.